# OPEN GL - Change Vertex position from a texture color

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures, shader, texture-mapping

I have a plane, made from a NURB surface, with many vertex so it can create a curved surface depending on the vertex positions ( control points ).

I bind the plane object with two different textures, one is the color texture to be displayed on the object, the other is an heightMap, ( black and white ), which has to alter de vertex `yy` positions of the plane depending of the color white in the correspondent texture coordinate.

I know the problem is in my shaders. I do not have many experience with OPENGL.

Here is the `shader.vert` that I use:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler2;

uniform float heightScale;

void main() {

//change texture coordinates
vec2 texInver=vec2(1.0, -1.0);

vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord*texInver;
//--------------------------

//change vertex position
vec4 filter = texture2D(uSampler2, vTextureCoord);

float offset = filter.r;

vec3 inc = vec3(0.0, offset, 0.0);

gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition + inc, 1.0);
//----------------------
}
```

Since the image is black and white, R = G = B. That is why I only check the `filter.r`

And my `shader.frag` is:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main() {
gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
}
```

This is the height map ( `.jpg` ):

[image]

The result I get is a plane all incremented by 1 in the `yy` coordinate.

The result I expect is SOME vertex of the plane to be incremented by a 0-1 value in the `yy` coordinate.

Comment: how do you specify the texture coordinates? If you assigned them wrong, it could result in giving every vertex the same tc, which then would happen to be the texture value 1.

Comment: ALso make sure the texture is properly set up. You should especially check the min/mag filters, because the default will use mipmapping, and texture sampling won't work if yourt texture is not miopmap complete. Mipmapping will also not work when sampling textures in the vertex shadder.

Comment: usualy, texCoord for height map are computed from vertex pos (in world coord) you divide them by your map width and height and you'll get tex coord of your heightmap ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: Thank you. I already solved the problem.
SOLVED: I was forgetting to change the number of the object's vertexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was forgetting to change the number of the object's vertexes

This was the problem, after I did that it was solved.